# Mapbox raster image not working in mobile

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, raster, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

[image]

In mobile view mapbox renders black image instead of raster image. I suspect this is because of the size of image(3.9 MB), also this is happening mostly on chrome browser for mobile. Please help me find the potential issue here?

Comment: You should provide some additional information. Could you provide a minimal example/codepen?
Since Mapbox is using WebGL for rendering you might hit a buffer limitation of the gpu with your image. What's the resolution of your image? It seems quite big.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't create codepen. The resolution of this image is around 4328*2318.

Comment: You could check https://webglreport.com/ with the device you know having this problem and check if your image width exceeds the "Max Texture Size" showing on webglreport. I had similar issues with huge textures in a game I was developing a few years ago.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds as if you could be running into the No-Data issue, when rendering transparency.

The black background that appears is the part of the raster image that does not contain any data. Generally a raster image is a rectangular grid of pixels. When you are working with data that is not rectangular, there are pixels within the grid that don't contain any data. These pixels are expressed as NoData values and represent the absence of data. GeoTIFFs that are uploaded to Mapbox Studio are displayed as JPEG to save space and make maps load quickly. Since JPEG cannot display transparency, NoData values appear black.

Please see this documentation on how to resolve this:

https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/raster-transparency-issues/#why-black-backgrounds-appear

Comment: I upvoted because while it is not certain this is the answer, it is highly likely. Anyone that runs across this question should look at this answer before anything else, especially if you are new with GeoTIFFs in general.